# Definition of finitely presented exact sequence $R^m→R^n→M→0$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$.
Let $M$ be $R$ module.

$R$module $M$ is said to be finitely presented if there exists integer $n,m$ and exact sequence $R^m→R^n→M→0$.

Regarding this definition, I have a question,

$g:R^n→M$ is given as follows. Suppose $M$ is generated by $ω_1,・・・,ω_n$ as $R$ module. Take $(a_1,・・・,a_n)\in R^n$, then $g$ is given by $(a_1,・・・,a_n)→a_1ω_1＋・・・a_nω_n$.

But **what is the map $f:R^m→R^n$** ?

How this map is defined?

P.S  My book Silverman's ''Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves'', p114 reads $f$ like $A$(m×n matrix), but I don't understand this notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having an exact sequence $R^n\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$ says exactly that $M$ is finitely generated.

For the same reason, when $R^m\rightarrow R^n\rightarrow M$ is an exact sequence, we are saying the kernel of the morphism from $R^n\rightarrow M$ is finitely generated.

It is these things together that make a finitely presented module: it's that you can map onto $M$ with a finite rank free module, and moreover the kernel of that map is expressible with finitely many generators.

The far left arrow doesn't have a special name or construction or anything. It just witnesses that the kernel is finitely generated.

Comment: My text book writes the far left allow as $A$(n×m matrix. What does this notation mean ?

Comment: @mathpencil Uh... any $R$ homomorphism of $R^m\rightarrow R^n$ is expressible as an $n\times m$ matrix over $R$, just like in linear algebra (except $R$ doesn't have to be a field of course.) Does that answer the question?